# Azure Bot framework AAD authentication problem

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, botframework, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to programmatically register and use an AAD application for the deployment of Microsoft Bot Framework bots into Azure in other people's tenants (thus az cli is not an option for us right now). Unfortunately, despite the AAD app being capable of acquiring tokens, we are getting auth errors.

AAD app creation PowerShell code

```
# Create Azure AD Application Registration
$rnd = Get-Random -Maximum 999 -Minimum 1        
$appName = $ApplicationName + [string]$rnd
$createAppBody = @{
    displayName = [string]$appName
    signInAudience = "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"
} | ConvertTo-Json
$createAppResponse = Invoke-RestMethod  -Method "POST"  -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications"  -Body $createAppBody -ContentType "application/json"  -Authentication Bearer -Token $AccessToken 

$appObjId = $createAppResponse.id
$appId = $createAppResponse.appId

# Add password to app registration
$addPasswordUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/" + $appObjId + "/addPassword"
$addPasswordBody = [PSCustomObject]@{
    passwordCredential = {
        displayName = $appName + "Password"
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json

$addPasswordResponse = Invoke-RestMethod  -Method  "POST" -Uri $addPasswordUri -Body $addPasswordBodyJson -ContentType "application/json"  -Authentication Bearer -Token $AccessToken 

$secret = $addPasswordResponse.secretText
```

These values successfully pass into our ARM deployment of the bot zip to the Microsoft.Web/sites with app settings including

```
        {
          "name": "MicrosoftAppId",
          "value": "[parameters('appId')]"
        },
        {
          "name": "MicrosoftAppPassword",
          "value": "[parameters('appSecret')]"
        },
```

Following the troubleshooting guide we can successfully acquire a token `curl -k -X POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=appid&client_secret=password&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.botframework.com%2F.default"`

I can see the correct guid in the settings for the bot channel.
[image: app id registered with bot service]

However, when we use the appid and password with the test client in the portal or with the emulator we get errors like
`POST https://webchat.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/JzddOS0PMku9aV9tU1HjVB-a/activities 502` with corresponding errors in the channel of

[image: auth error]

I've looked at an AAD app created by the az cli command given in the docs and can't spot any differences. The arm deploy generator doesn't include any additional variables or mention any role assignments required.

Does anyone know what else is needed to correct this auth problem or diagnose further?

Comment: You missed a "&" between `client_id=appid` and `client_secret=password`. Are you sure you can successfully acquire a token?

Comment: @AllenWu yes i can, i just overwrote the `&` accidentally whilst removing the guids

Comment: Did you try to send the activity using Postman?

Comment: The token acquisition? I used curl. For the bot interactions, no I used the msft bot tools (test chat in browser and locally the emulator)

Comment: I mean could you please try to use Postman to send the activity? (not token acquisition). Check if the same issue will occur.

Comment: @StephLocke is there an error correlation id and timestamp that you can share?